# Changing File name Dynamically in linux bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to change a filename "Domain_20181012230112.csv" to "Domain_12345_20181012230112.csv" where "Domain" and "12345" are constants while 20181012230112 is always gonna change but with fix length. In bash how can I do this

Comment: Use the `mv` command.

Comment: `rename Domain Domain_12345 Domain_*.csv`. You could replace the `*` in the file selection pattern with an appropriate amount of `?` if there are files with a different amount of digits you would like to avoid renaming

Comment: I want it in shell but filename is changing so I just want to add one word in existing file and keeping rest same.
mv commands need both names to be known exact.

Comment: Thanx @Dominique for help

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to replace `Domain_` with `Domain_12345_`, then just do

```
for file in Domain_*; 
do
    mv "$file" "${file/Domain_/Domain_12345_}"
done
```

You can make it even shorter if you know that there will only be one underscore:

```
...
    mv "$file" "${file/_/_12345_}"
...
```

See [string substitutions](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for more info.

Comment: While this is the working answer (+1), the [`rename`/`prename`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/prename/) based option (see comment by Aaron to the question) is shorter to write. So, in case you are unaware of it, it's a good tool to add to your quiver.

Comment: That's true, and `rename` is a great tool. I wanted to suggest an option without additional packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the date command to get the date and time information you want

```
date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
# 2018-10-26 10:25:47
```

To then use the result within the filename, you can put it in `` to evaluate it inline, for example you can run

```
echo "Domain_12345_`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`"
# Domain_12345_2018-10-26 10:29:17
```

You can use the date's man page to figure out the option for milliseconds to add es well.

```
man date
```

There are different options like %m and %d for example that always have leading zeroes if necessary, so the file name length stays constant.

To then rename the file you can use the mv (move) command

```
mv "Domain_20181012230112.csv" "Domain_12345_`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`.csv"
```

Good luck with the rest of the exercise!

Comment: Thanx @Meral Harbes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mv` in a `for` loop, like this:

```
for file in Domain_??????????????.csv ; do ts=`echo ${file} | cut -c8-21`; mv ${file} Domain_12345_${ts}.csv; done
```

Given the one file of your example, this will essentially execute this command

```
mv Domain_20181012230112.csv Domain_12345_20181012230112.csv
```

Comment: thanx @Würgspaß

Comment: @RohitAher If you like the answer, just click on the upper to mark it as useful and on the tick to accept it.